# Fetch / Filter Items in RSS feed by a different parameter.

Tags: rss

Currently everything in my RSS Feed(s) get pulled by published date.  I would like to pull the items by a date specified in the post somehow (as a meta tag?).  I'm doing this for events so they can display in the feed by upcoming event as opposed to published date.

Comment: Where are you storing the event date at the moment - in a custom field?

Comment: Yes the event date is in it's own custom field.